# Sass: Absolute references inside nested selectors

Tags: sass

In Sass, is there any way to use root/top-level selectors inside a nested element? This would be useful.

For example, I want to define the same style for all root-level `a` tags and `li` tags *only* inside `ul`. Here's a imaginary example where `/` accomplishes this:

```
ul {
    li, /a {
       color:black;
    }
}
```

The rendered stylesheet would then look like this:

```
a {
    color: black;
}

ul li {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use selective inheritance using `@extend`. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

This `file.scss`

```
ul {
  li,
  li a {
    color:black
  }
}
```

Will compile to this

```
ul li,
ul li a {
  color: black;
}
```

Isn't that what you wanted?

---

UPDATE: What you're trying to achieve is possible with `@extend`

Comment: Your example still renders a nested object. I updated my question to display what kind of output is desired.